# Knockout.js: Sum grouped values within table and foreach

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

The table with the data-bindings currently looks like below:

```
Source        Calls     ChargeableCalls

Car Insurance
08434599111     3            2
08934345122     2            1

Home Insurance
08734599333     3            2
08034345555     2            1
```

The **desired output** should be like in the bellow example, The table should contain total values for `Calls` and `ChargeableCalls` grouped by Division, and total values for all `Calls` and `ChargeableCalls` within the table.

```
Source          Calls         ChargeableCalls

Car Insurance
08434599154       3                  2
08934345555       2                  1
Total Calls       5     Total CC     3

Home Insurance
08434599154       6                  3
08934345555       1                  0
Total Calls       7     Total CC     3

Total Calls All  24     Total CC All 12
```

Here are the bindings within the table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="reportData">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>TotalCalls</th>
        <th>ChargeableCalls</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: groups">
     <!-- ko foreach: $root.getGroup($data) -->
    <tr data-bind="if: $index() == 0">
        <td colspan="3" data-bind="text: division" class="division"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: source"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: totalCalls"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: chargeableCalls"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

Here's my ViewModel:

```
function GroupedReportingViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.results = ko.observableArray();

    self.groupedResults = {};

    self.getGroup = function (group) {
       return self.groupedResults[group];
    };

    self.groupedResultsC = ko.computed(function () {
        self.groupedResults = {};
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.results(), function (r) {
           if (!self.groupedResults[r.division]) self.groupedResults[r.division] = [];
                        self.groupedResults[r.division].push(r);
                    });
           return self.groupedResults;
                });

     self.groups = ko.computed(function () {
         var g = [];
         for (x in self.groupedResultsC())
                g.push(x);
                return g;_
       });
    }

     var model = new GroupedReportingViewModel();
     ko.applyBindings(model);
```

The `results` observableArray gets populated from an ajax response, like below:

```
success: function (jsondata) {
        model.results(jsondata["Data"]["Report"]);
}
```

The `jsondata` object looks like below:

```
{"Data":
    {"Report":[ {"source":"08434599494","division":"Car Insurance","totalCalls":5, "chargeableCalls":23},
                {"source":"08434599172","division":"Car Insurance","totalCalls":512,"chargeableCalls":44},
                {"source":"08434599129","division":"Home  Insurance","totalCalls":4, "chargeableCalls":2},
                {"source":"08434599215","division":"Home Insurance","totalCalls":234, "chargeableCalls":54},
                {"source":"08434599596","division":"Car Insurance","totalCalls":332, "chargeableCalls":266}
              ]
    }
}
```

**Q:** How can I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, groupedResults is a list of arrays.  Instead of this, try making a ViewModel for a group.  This ViewModel can then be used for working out the totals.  For example...

```
function GroupViewModel(division) {
    var self = this;
    self.Division = division;
    self.Items = ko.observableArray();
    self.Count = ko.computed(function() { 
        var count = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Items(), function(r) { count += r.totalCalls; });
        return count; 
    });
    self.ChargeableCount = ko.computed(function() { 
        var count = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Items(), function(r) { count += r.chargeableCalls; });
        return count; 
    });
}
```

You can simplify your main Viewmodel too, and push the items into the GroupViewModel instead:

```
function GroupedReportingViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.results = ko.observableArray();
    self.groupedResults = ko.computed(function() {
        var groups = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Results(), function(r) {
            var g = ko.utils.arrayFirst(groups, function(g) { return g.Division === r.division; });
            if (!g) {
                g = new GroupViewModel(r.division);
                groups.push(g);
            }
            g.Items.push(r);
        });
        return groups;
    });
    self.TotalCount = ko.computed(function() { 
        var count = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.results(), function(r) { count += r.totalCalls; });
        return count; 
    });
    self.TotalChargeableCount = ko.computed(function() { 
        var count = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.results(), function(r) { count += r.chargeableCalls; });
        return count; 
    });
}
```

Finally in your view, iterate through the groups, and then the items:

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: groupedResults -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" data-bind="text: Division" class="division"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: Items -->
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: source"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: totalCalls"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: chargeableCalls"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <tr>
        <td>Total Calls</td>
        <td data-bind="text: Count"></td>
        <td>Total Chargeable:</td>
        <td data-bind="text: ChargeableCount"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <tr>
        <td>Total Calls All</td>
        <td data-bind="text: TotalCount"></td>
        <td>Total Chargeable All</td>
        <td data-bind="text: TotalChargeableCount"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Sorry, one last criticism, `groupedResults` must be an array. You can't `foreach` on an object.

Comment: Fixed.  If the dataset were large I'd make it more efficient, but this is simple.

Comment: It works great, thanks mate! Adding the total all values for `Total Calls` and `Total Chargeable Calls` within the table would require an additional ViewModel?

Comment: No, just add a computed on the top level viewmodel

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you tell me how will this perform if the dataset were to increase to large over time?